# Calling an optional method in superclass (Objective-C)

Tags: objective-c, inheritance, macros, nscoding, overriding

I'm trying to create a generic implementation for the NSCoding protocol.
The code will be wrapped around in a macro the will implement NSCoding.
In order to implement the protocol, we need two functions:

```
-(void)encodeWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder;
```

A generic implementation of the initWithCoder function would be:

```
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder { 
    if ([super conformsToProtocol:@protocol(NSCoding)]) 
        self = [super initWithCoder:coder];
    else {
        self = [super init];
    }
    if (!self) return self;
    self = [MyGenericCoder initWithCoder:coder forObject:self withClass:[__clazz class]]; 
    return self; 
}
```

The problematic line is `self = [super initWithCoder:coder];` it will not compile since super does not respond to `initWithCoder:` when we use the in a class that its super does not implements NSCoding. Casting super to `NSObject<NSCoding>*` will not work with the LLVM compiler.

`[super performSelector:(initWithCoder:) withObject:coder]` will not work either since super == self, Which will result in an infinite loop.

How can I call `[super initWithCoder:coder]` in manner that will trigger the function in the superclass and will not generate a compilation warning / error?

Comment: By 'it will not compile' you presumably mean you get warnings? Unless you have the relevant compiler option set to treat warnings as errors then I think it should at least compile. What does LLVM think if you just cast super to `(id)`?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `+instancesRespondToSelector:` to find out if your superclass responds to the selector, and then `objc_msgSendSuper()` directly to actually call it.

```
#import <objc/message.h>

- (id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder *)coder {
    // Note: use [__clazz superclass] directly because we need the
    // compile-time superclass instead of the runtime superclass.
    if ([[__clazz superclass] instancesRespondToSelector:_cmd]) {
        struct objc_super sup = {self, [__clazz superclass]};
        ((id(*)(struct objc_super *, SEL, NSCoder*))objc_msgSendSuper)(&sup, _cmd, coder);
    } else {
        [super init];
    }
    if (!self) return self;
    self = [MyGenericCoder initWithCoder:coder forObject:self withClass:[__clazz class]];
    return self;
}
```

Comment: [My solution](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12116975/1300347) finds the superclass in runtime. Why do think its necessary to find it in compile time?

Comment: @TomerShiri: No it doesn't. You're also referencing `__clazz`, which I'm assuming is a `Class` passed to the macro. That's the compile-time aspect. The caution was to avoid trying to figure it out based on `self`.

Answer (score 0):

```
#import <objc/runtime.h>
-(id)initWithCoder:(NSCoder*)coder {
    Class superclass = class_getSuperclass([__clazz class]);
    SEL constructor = @selector(initWithCoder:);
    if (class_conformsToProtocol(superclass,@protocol(NSCoding))) {
        self = class_getMethodImplementation(superclass,constructor)(self,constructor,coder);
    }
    else {
        self = [super init];
    }
    if (!self) return self;
    self = [MyGenericCoder initWithCoder:coder forObject:self withClass:[__clazz class]];
    return self;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

> How can I call [super initWithCoder:coder] in manner that will trigger the function in the superclass and will not generate a compilation warning / error?

Just create two variants of your macro -- one for types whose superclasses adopt `NSCoding`, and another for those which do not.

Either that, or abstract the detail from yourself and derive from intermediate types which abstract the condition from your bases and adopts `NSCopying` -- then you can just call `initWithCoder:` on any such type.